# AngularJS rotate array values in divs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array and I need to divide (by 5) and display it's elements in 5 rows (divs) in 5 second intervals. 
ex: if array size is 15, it should first display 0..4 and second iteration it should display 5...9 and last iteration 10..15 on the given 5 divs.

I have created a fiddle which is working fine.

my issue here is, I get this array filled dynamically after sometime the page loads, not at the application start time. because of that, it doesn't loop the array as above. (to manipulate this, I have put a settimeout to the above fiddle.) It does not work with settimeout, if I commented it out, then it works since the array is already loaded at page start.

please help on fixing this issue..

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nc295bny/39/)

```
//setTimeout(function(){ 
             $scope.resutls = [{number:'1',name:'SHE SO CUTE'},
                     {number:'2',name:'SHE SO CUTE1'},
                     {number:'3',name:'SHE SO CUTE2'},
                     {number:'4',name:'SHE SO CUTE3'},
                     {number:'5',name:'SHE SO CUTE4'},
                     {number:'6',name:'SHE SO CUTE5'},
                     {number:'7',name:'SHE SO CUTE6'},
                     {number:'8',name:'SHE SO CUTE7'},
                     {number:'9',name:'SHE SO CUTE8'},
                     {number:'10',name:'SHE SO CUTE9'},
                     {number:'11',name:'SHE SO CUTE10'},
                     {number:'12',name:'SHE SO CUTE11'},
                     {number:'13',name:'SHE SO CUTE12'},
                     {number:'14',name:'SHE SO CUTE13'},
                     {number:'15',name:'SHE SO CUTE14'},
                     {number:'16',name:'SHE SO CUTE15'}];


//}, 3000);
```

Comment: your fiddle is blank

Comment: updated, sorry @Anita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put the code which starts your intervals in a function, and call that function when the data arrives:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
             $scope.resutls = [{number:'1',name:'SHE SO CUTE'},
                     {number:'2',name:'SHE SO CUTE1'},
                     {number:'3',name:'SHE SO CUTE2'},
                     {number:'4',name:'SHE SO CUTE3'},
                     {number:'5',name:'SHE SO CUTE4'},
                     {number:'6',name:'SHE SO CUTE5'},
                     {number:'7',name:'SHE SO CUTE6'},
                     {number:'8',name:'SHE SO CUTE7'},
                     {number:'9',name:'SHE SO CUTE8'},
                     {number:'10',name:'SHE SO CUTE9'},
                     {number:'11',name:'SHE SO CUTE10'},
                     {number:'12',name:'SHE SO CUTE11'},
                     {number:'13',name:'SHE SO CUTE12'},
                     {number:'14',name:'SHE SO CUTE13'},
                     {number:'15',name:'SHE SO CUTE14'},
                     {number:'16',name:'SHE SO CUTE15'}];
      start();
  //alert("Hello"); 
}, 3000);
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7qenxoy/).